# Does Gordy Formula measure default risk & downgrade risk?

Tags: credit-risk, merton-model, default-risk

The Gordy Formula used for measuring Credit Risk as proposed in Basel Rules is based on the asymptotic single risk factor model. It is derived from a Merton Model. The Merton Model only knows to stati, i.e. performing or defaulted.

Is it therefore fair to say that the formula calculates default risk, but not the risk of a rating downgrade which will also lead to a loss until held to maturity?

Comment: Can you please add more details, specifically, which formula you refer to? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model (and models like it) seem to suggest an issuer or entity is, by time $T>0$, in one of two states: defaulted or not.  Money is lost only on a default.

Comment: And what about downgrade ?

Comment: Downgrades are like marking-to-market as you move towards default.  So in that sense, this formula doesn't mark-to-market--it just incurs the losses on defaults.